# Javascript -- how to click anywhere on page to hide opened div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript that opens up a hidden div:

```
<script>
function dropdown() 
{ document.getElementById("login_dropdown").style.display="block"; }
</script>
```

The html is:

```
<div onclick="dropdown()">
<div id="login_dropdown">STUFF</div>
</div>
```

The CSS is:

```
<style>
#login_dropdown {
width: 150px;
display:none;
}</style>
```

Using javascript alone, how can I hide this div when I click anywhere else on the page, **excluding** the opened DIV itself.

Comment: You can set up a click handler on the body element to handle all clicks on the page iirc. Then you just need the handler to hide the element.

Comment: Could someone show me on jFiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function closest(e, t){ 
  return !e? false : e === t ? true : closest(e.parentNode, t);
}

container = document.getElementById("popup");
open = document.getElementById("open");

open.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  container.style.display = "block";
  open.disabled = true;
  e.stopPropagation();
});

document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (!closest(e.target, container)) {
        container.style.display = "none";
        open.disabled = false;
    }
});
```

```css
#popup {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  display: none;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button id="open">open</button>
  <div id="popup">PopUp</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Something like this with vanilljs

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
   const yourContainer = document.querySelector('....');
   if(!yourContainer.contains(event.target)) {
      //hide things classes.. yourContainer.classList.add('hidden');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this

```
var elem = document.getElementById("login_dropdown");
(document.body || document.documentElement).addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  // If the element on which the click event occurs is not the dropdown, then hide it
  if (event.target !== elem)
    elem.style.display="none";
}, false);
```

Comment: Would I place this code in:

    <script>function dropdown() { ... } </script>

I'm new to javascript

Comment: What about child elements? If you click an element inside your container the whole thing will be hidden.

Comment: Inside a script placed as the last child of `<body>` because it queries for `#login_dropdown`, so if you place it inside the `head` tag, when `document.getElementById("login_dropdown")` executes, the DOM tree has not been attached with those elements inside the `body` yet, so it will return `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$("document").mouseup(function(e)
  {
    var subject = $("#login_dropdown");

    if(e.target.id != subject.attr('id'))
    {
        subject.css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

works like this. When you click anywhere on the page, the handler fires and compares the ID of the open tab vs the id of the document (which there is none) - so it closes the tab. However, if you click the tab, the handler fires, checks the ID, sees the target is the same and fails the test (thus not closing the tab).

Comment: I need strictly javascript.